# Remove text between two tokens including tokens in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a hostfile with two markings in there *somewhere* and I need to remove all lines between the two markings including the markings.

I found this command in another question:

```
cat hostfile | grep -P '(?<=##STARTMARK).*(?=##ENDMARK)'
```

but that still leaves the markers in there.

I currently have this

```
127.0.0.1 home-host.dev

##STARTMARK
127.0.0.1 a-blocked-host.com
##ENDMARK
```

and I want this

```
127.0.0.1 home-host.dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `sed`,

```
sed '/##STARTMARK/,/##ENDMARK/d' hostfile
127.0.0.1 home-host.dev
```

Note the second line (i.e., the blank line) would be kept since they are not embraced by the tokens as your criteria.